# Blind man working for a secret organisation gets a super power(Slow Motion vision)

Tags: science-fiction

So there is a blind man (age~25) who secretly works for an organisation. Suddenly one day, the blind man gets a super power i.e HOUSE FLY vision. He can see in slo mo(7 times slower than humans) for 10 house fly secs(70 human secs). 
Other than eyes no other body part can move when the power gets activated. After playing with the power for sometime, he realizes that he was given this power for a purpose. He thinks about that. He assumes that this has to do with the organisation. About the secret organisation, it hires blind people for their projects. What kind of projects can they be working on? & how would slo mo vision can only interpret what they are working on? I am stuck at this part of the story. The organisation may be working on good or bad projects, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi Heis3nberg, welcome to Worldbuilding! As of now, your question is too story-based. Do you mind trying to edit it so it can become generic?

Comment: As for the answer, I am struggling to find efficient use for this superpower. Modern recording devices can provide much better slow motion capabilities, and user's inability to react during slow motion phase renders it even less useful. Maybe he can sneak to training practice of professional sport teams and read signs used by players - all without the use of any recording devices?

Comment: @Alexander As of now, It's more of a story-based one. Now I got an idea of what to post in the exchange(not story-based ones). Thank you :)